# Can't see Team Project nor Build Definition in Release Management Update 2

Tags: tfs, release-management, ms-release-management

So I've tried to setup Release Management for Visual Studio 2013 Update 2, with TFS 2010 as source. Authentication, in the Administration panel, succeeds (validates), but when I define a new release, the Team Project and Build Definition drop-down are blank.

[image]

What could I be doing wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

Seems I am not [the only one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d5796bed-42be-494c-82b7-f2a6d7c682b1/release-template-build-definition-team-project-empty?forum=tfsbuild) with this issue. Time to downgrade or start with blank database..

**UPDATE 2**

Deleting the databse did not resolve this issue.

**UPDATE 3**

Switching Release Management Server to listen on HTTP instead of the default HTTPS, resolved this issue for me.

[image]

I hope this saves someone lots of grief.

If I had to guess, I'd say because it is secure environment, 2008 R2 SP1, I was getting certificate errors in the background.

Comment: Could you please try switching the web app in IIS to anonymous authentication? I know it sounds like a hack but it worked in my case but I can't reproduce it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, until more details of this issues can be obtained, use HTTP instead of the default HTTPS protocol, for the Release Management Server.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Looking in the Event Viewer on the Release Management / TFS server I found an error that expressed that i didn't have access to TFS.

```
Message: User THEDOMAIN\RoddaMi does not have access to http://TFSSERVER:8080/tfs/VanquisCollection: \r\n\r\n   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Platform.Common.TfsOnPremConnector.GetTfsUserIdentity(Uri tfsUri, String serviceUserName, String serviceUserPassword, String impersonatingUserName)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Platform.Common.TfsOnPremConnector.GetTeamProjectCollectionWithImpersonation(Uri tfsUri, String serviceUserName, String serviceUserPassword, String impersonatingUserName)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Builds.TfsOnPrem.TfsOnPremBuildSystem.<GetTeamProjects>d__6.MoveNext()
```